# Ring structure on tensor product of two $A$-modules

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

Let $A, B, C$ be a commutative rings. 
Suppose I have two ring homomorphisms,
$\alpha : A \rightarrow B$ and $\beta : A \rightarrow C$.
I am trying to show that $B \otimes_A C$ has a ring structure defined 
by $(b_1 \otimes c_1)(b_2 \otimes c_2) = (b_1 b_2\otimes c_1c_2)$.

I am having trouble proving that this is well defined. Could someone please 
explain me how this can be done? Thanks!

(In particular, I am interested in knowing if $b_1 \otimes c_1= b'_1 \otimes c'_1$
and $b_2 \otimes c_2= b'_2 \otimes c'_2$, then $b_1 b_2\otimes c_1c_2 = b'_1 b'_2\otimes c'_1c'_2$.)

Answer (score 4):

The only nontrivial part is to show that multiplication in the ring respects the action of $A$:
$$(a.b_1 \otimes c_1)(b_2 \otimes c_2)
=(a.b_1 b_2) \otimes c_1 c_2 = b_1 b_2\otimes (a.c_1c_2) = (b_1 \otimes a.c_1)(b_2\otimes c_2),$$
where $a.b = \alpha(a)b$ and $a.c = \beta(a)c$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am particularly stuck on the well defined part, do you happen to know how that can be done? Thanks!

Comment: That is the explanation of the well-defined part. A map $B\otimes_A C \to X$ is just a map $f:B \times C \to X$ with $f(a.b, c) = f(b, a.c)$.